# Azure maps excessive hits

Tags: azure, azure-maps

Currently I use azure maps fuzzy search ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/maps/search/getsearchfuzzy )

So when I do a search using GET [https://atlas.microsoft.com/search/fuzzy/json?subscription-key={subscription-key}&api-version=1.0&query=1600 Pennsylvania ave Washington DC 20500](https://atlas.microsoft.com/search/fuzzy/json?subscription-key=%7Bsubscription-key%7D&api-version=1.0&query=1600%20Pennsylvania%20ave%20Washington%20DC%2020500) I get several results, including POI and Point Address.

This event is triggered off of an onblur event from an address change.

Last month we got billed for 5,000,000 hits from Azure when we didn't have near that many. That number should have been closer to 6000.

Is that because I am using the fuzzy search or what? I can't seem to find any information on why our hits would have been so high.

Comment: You say it's triggered from onblur ... is the browser calling Azure Maps _directly_?

Comment: Yes, every onblur event of address or zip code, we build the url to make sure we have the correct longitude and latitude.

Comment: Well... If it's a publicly accessible site, how are you making sure that people don't steal your subscriptionkey and run up a tab for, say, 5,000,000 hits on your dime (since, if you are calling Azure directly from the browser, your subKey by definition can be seen by anyone who can load your page...)

Comment: Thatis the first thing I checked and immediately reset it. No change in traffic.

Comment: As Michael mentioned, without seeing code or a link to a site to test we can't do much. The API only registers a single transaction each time the REST call is made. So if you have 5M transactions, your key was used in 5M REST API calls. These calls would be made from your application. Check the network traffic and see if perhaps your code is making a lot more calls. Perhaps onkey press/up is being used, would be the only way I can see 6000 becoming anywhere close to 5M, even then that's still means over 800 calls are being made per user which would certainly have perf impact on your page.

Answer (score 1):

The delta seems absurdly high (6000 vs 5,000,000). Are all those 5,000,000 calls, Search Fuzzy API calls?

Can't say much without looking at the actual code but if the behavior is that in your app the "user adds an address in a form field" and when the "user finishes adding the address and clicks outside that address box (onBlur event fires)" and calls Azure Maps Search Fuzzy API - that would be **one** call (irrespective of it returning multiple/different categories of addresses POIs, Point Addresses etc.) - [Unless you are using the API in the "predictive" mode (param typeahead = true) and calling the API everytime the user enters a character]

I would try and check the number of calls going out to Azure Maps using any network capture tool (Fiddler/Browser n/w capture) and if they look okay then check the Azure Maps metrics for "Search Fuzzy API" in the Azure Portal to see if they look ok.

But if you are only making an explicit call to the API manually once the user finishes adding/editing the address then I don't see a reason why that call won't be recorded as 1 call on the Azure Maps side.